# Clarity + Angular6: Tree View Node Listener (clr-tree-node)

Tags: angular, angular6, treenode, clarity, angular-event-emitter

I'm trying to track changes made to the tree nodes data source.
Each node has a *selected* property which reflects the node selection status, every time I select a node, I need to emit the selection to another component, which will build another tree according to that selection.

I tried with OnChanges interface, but I read later in the doc that ngOnChanges is called only when data is set again.

This is my simple template:

```
   <clr-tree-node [(clrSelected)]="selected" >
        Asset
        <ng-template [clrIfExpanded]="true">
            <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let asset of assets" [(clrSelected)]="asset.selected">
                {{asset.type}}
            </clr-tree-node>
        </ng-template>
    </clr-tree-node>
```

Is there a tree node event I can bind I can use to emit (with EventEmitter) the changed data? For example onSelectionChange, or onChange or something else? 
Or any other mechanism?

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are already binding to that event. Just use the long form of the two way binding:

template.html

```
<clr-tree-node [clrSelected]="selected" (clrSelectedChange)="changeSelected($event)">
    Asset
    <ng-template [clrIfExpanded]="true">
        <clr-tree-node 
            *ngFor="let asset of assets 
            [clrSelected]="asset.selected"
            (clrSelectedChange)="changeSelectedAsset(asset, $event)"
        >{{asset.type}}</clr-tree-node>
    </ng-template>
</clr-tree-node>
```

component.ts

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComp {
    @Output public structureChange:EventEmitter<...> = new EventEmitter<...>();

    public changeSelected(data):void {
        this.selected = data;
        this.structureChange.emit(data);
    }
    public changeSelectedAsset(asset, data):void {
        asset.selected = data;
        this.structureChange.emit(this.selected);
    }
}
```

Something like this. Of course, add datatypes wherever possible.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was missing the (clrSelectedChange) binding :-)